# Java while loop endlessly catching mismatch exception

Tags: java, loops, exception, while-loop, try-catch

I'm trying to create a simple while loop in java that asks the user for a number and stores it in a variable. I'm also checking to make sure the value they entered is a number. The loop should tell the user that they did not enter a number if they entered a string. It should also ask the user to enter a number again after it tells them they didn't enter a number.

At the moment this code endlessly catches the exception if the user input a string. How do I get this loop to work?

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
isInt = false;  
while(!isInt){
    try{
        System.out.println("Enter a number");                    
        int aNumber = reader.nextInt();
        isInt = true;
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("You didn't enter a number");
    }    
}
```

Comment: check for `Number format exception` using parseInt

Comment: Get more familiar with the [scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class to use / check the input for number. If user does not enter a number then end the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nextInt()` method is not consuming the non-numeric input.  This method's Javadocs refer to the overloaded method [`nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--), which states:

> Scans the next token of the input as an int. This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int value as described below. **If the translation is successful**, the scanner advances past the input that matched.

(emphasis mine)

In the `catch` block, add a line that calls `reader.next()` to consume (and ignore) the non-numeric input, so that the next token can be examined in the next iteration of your `while` loop.